Exception isn't shown, Flutter with Visual Studio Code
I have a problem that in my Drawer I have a tile which is used for logging out:
ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.logout,
                ),
                title: Text("Wyloguj się"),
                onTap: () async {
                  DownloaderModel().reset();
                  final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;
                  final googleManager = GoogleManager();
                  print(supabase.auth.currentSession != null
                      ? "user is still logged in"
                      : "user is logged out");
                  try {
                    await googleManager.signOut();

                    await supabase.auth.signOut();

                    if (context.mounted) {
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>  LoginPage()));
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    print("Failed to log out!!! with error: $e");
                  }
                }),
          ],
        ));

And when I click the button then there is exception which isn't caught by try/catch block. Google and Supabase is successfully logged out, probably there is a problem with
Navigator.pushReplacement(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) =>  LoginPage()));
}

I only know about excception, because there is application freeze and there is information from VSC.

And I can't see where exceprion occured. Is this possible that Navigator.pushReplacement creates exception, because of usage in Scaffold's Drawer? Do someone know how to fix it or see exception details?

Try removing that part of the code (Navigator.push...), or some other element, to rule out which one is causing the problem.
If it is the LoginPage() , check that it is not loading deleted items, requiring permissions or similar.

LoginPage() is causing error, but only if I logout. On app start there is no problem.

Can you share your code of that screen? Also try adding some breakpoints in login() so you can see if the error occurs when starting or some intermediate component.

You can also try redirecting to the login screen but without logging out, this way you rule out that it is not due to some session permission
